# Unable to select the link with link_text in selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, linktext, partiallinktext

I am new to automation and trying to automate a website with links in it. When I tried hardcoding the user name and password and then selecting the link using Link_text, the code worked, But When I tried fetching data from Excel file for user name and password, the user name and password field works but the link is not getting selected. Can someone please help?

This is the code

```
    import XLutils
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    
    driver.get("https://test.com")
    
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    path = r'C:\Users\test\Desktop\Reports Test.xlsx'
    
    rows = XLutils.getRowCount(path, 'Login')
    
    username = XLutils.readData(path, "Login", 2, 1)
    password = XLutils.readData(path, "Login", 2, 2)
    
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username').clear()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').clear()
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/body/div/app-login/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/form/div\[4\]/button').click()
    
    driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Offer Activity').click()
```

html

```
<a class="reportLink" href="null"> Offer Activity </a>
```

Comment: As per the details provided, the `LINK_TEXT` is `Import Offer Activity`. Try the full text or try with `partial_link _text`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The link name I added in the code is Import Offer activity.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Offer Activity').click()
```

to

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Offer Activity')]").click()
```

Comment: That did not work too, It works if I hard code the user name and password but when I use data-driven just for user name and password and then try to click the link it doesn't. If you have any other ideas let me know. Thank You

Comment: If it works when you're hard-coding the username and password, it sounds like you need to ensure you're getting the correct data from `username = XLutils.readData(path, "Login", 2, 1)` as well as `password = XLutils.readData(path, "Login", 2, 2)`  -- Do you notice the correct information (username, password) being sent to the screen before it clicks? If you can't tell, add a `driver.explicit_wait(10)` before you click to check the data being sent.

Comment: yes, I see the right information being sent and log in to the application with that data. The link for the report I am trying to open (offer activity) is inside the application and that is where it stops.

Comment: Could you post the output of the error you're getting?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":" Offer Activity"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)

Comment: That is the error you get after changing the code I noted originally?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(), 'Offer Activity')]"}